# Why is not both sides of a fan equally effective?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, flow, fan

I have a fan on my desktop. I started to wondering if it would not be just as effective if I flipped it 180 degrees. Since all the wind that comes out of the front has to be sucked in from behind, right?

But it was not. It felt much less effective. I don't have any equipment to perform any actual measurements, but the cooling effect was MUCH lower. I cannot say I noticed anything. It was like having it turned off. Why is this?